# Summing array in liquid

Tags: liquid

Trying to sum all elements of an array in liquid in NationBuilder. First I create an array of donations created after a certain date. Then, I try to sum the values of my array. I can't seem to find a way to sum. Here's what I have so far:

```
{% capture d_list %}
  {% for donation in signup.donation %}
    {% if donation.succeeded_at | date: %s > 1483228801 %}
      {{ recipient.donation_amount_in_cents }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.last %},{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign d_array = d_list | split:"," %}
```

Any thoughts at all are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First we create the variable sum and assign it to 0. Then for each donation in the signup.donation array we assign the date since the unix epoch and then add the value to sum if it matches the criteria.

```
  {% assign sum = 0 %}
  {% for donation in signup.donation %}
    {% assign date = donation.succeeded_at | date: %s %}
    {% if date > 1483228801 %}
      {% assign sum = sum | plus: donation %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {{ sum }}
```